# setting limit on concurrent tasks in AFNetworking 2 running AFHTTPSessionManager

Tags: ios, network-programming, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

so I know that in the old AFNetworking this was possible using the AFHTTPClient,
and I know that if I use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager I can set the queue's limit, but I can't make AFHTTPSessionManager to run only x requests at a time without implementing it by myself using the success block (which I don't want to).

The following code did NOT limit my connections:

> AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
>       manager.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

In line with an interesting discussion [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/953), I have a lot of requests to my server and I choke it until I get timeouts, so I really need to limit my concurrent connections.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`AFHTTPSessionManager` uses tasks instead of operations (`NSURLSessionDataTask`, specifically), which is why you can't set an operation queue.

As you can see in [the implementation of this class](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.m), tasks are immediately started (`[task resume]`) and not added to any sort of queue.

Consequently, and unfortunately, there is no built-into-AFNetworking way to set a limit to the number of concurrent tasks using `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

Possible alternatives:

1. Use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` instead (this is what I'm doing)
2. Build an `NSOperation` subclass that has a task as a property, and start the task in the `[operation start]` method of your subclass
3. Create a Grand Central serial queue and create and start tasks in this queue
4. If your requests are all to the same host, directly access the `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` option in the foundation URL loading system, like so:

   ```
   [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration].HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 4;
   ```

   This approach has a number of caveats, which are discussed in [the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you wind up doing #2, please submit it as a pull request to AFNetworking - it would be a welcome addition.

Comment: Thanks you for the detailed answer, I ended up doing #1, which was the simplest.

Comment: @LeszekS Still the same.

Comment: @AaronBrager Will there be an option to set the # of maximum concurrent operations on `AFHTTPSessionManager` in **AFNetworking 3** since `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is removed?

Comment: @adamup [Doesn't look like it.](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/1272e3e32dbd447d18d75bc35e7a2f0f04f33d61/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.m#L115)

Comment: If you still need maxConcurrentOperationCount in AFNetworking 3 then you can check my fork https://github.com/fins/AFNetworking and use AFHTTPOperationSessionManager instead of AFHTTPSessionManager. It wraps tasks in NSOperations so you can set requestsOperationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount to anything you need :) If you are using pods then you can just edit podfile like this: `pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/fins/AFNetworking.git'`

Answer (score 3):

You can configure `AFHTTPSessionManager` `NSURLSessionConfiguration`:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
config.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 2;

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:config];
```