# AFHTTPSessionManager calling Multiple Web service or batch with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I need to call multiple web services in a loop for uploading and downloading the data for application.(Known as Sync Process)

I am using AFHTTPSessionManager and create a subclass/wrappper class for that.
I need to do something in a que or creating batch request for that.

I am stuck at this from last night.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of funcionalities probably an `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is a better choice.
SessionManager relies on tasks, tasks don't have the knowledge of dependency between each other, while operations does.
You have different possibilities:

- Wrap sessions into a dispatch_group  take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414486/how-to-batch-request-with-afnetworking-2)
- Try to embed a session task inside an `NSOperation` (really hard)
- Use `AFHTTPOperation` and add dependencies between operations
- Use a serial queue on GCD

You might find also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411979/setting-limit-on-concurrent-tasks-in-afnetworking-2-running-afhttpsessionmanager) helpful